# Points in iOS versus size units in CSS in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview

When you load HTML into a UIWebView in iOS, how do you get iOS point units in the CSS? That is, point units within iOS are a relative size measurement, relative to the size of the display. How do you get those relative point units in CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Originally, I had a bug in my program, undiagnosed for quite a while where I assumed that the CSS "pt" unit was the iOS points. But, rather, it looks like the "px" units in CSS in the UIWebView actually corresponds to iOS points.

Comment: Similar experience. Any idea why pt=px in UIWebView?  Is this a bug in iOS?

Comment: Bug or feature? I don't know. Seems like an odd unit naming correspondence in any event.

Comment: "pt" in css and "pt" in ios are completely different concept.  pt in ios means 1pt = 2px in retina and 1pt = 1px in non-retina devices.  pt in css means 1pt = 1/72 of 1in.  They just happen to have a same name